# Anchor links in a map area with firefox

Tags: html, firefox, anchor

I have a strange problem: I have an image with anchors:

```
<img src="http://www.somesite.com/cartina_italia_vers_2.png"  alt="" border="0" usemap="#Map" />
<map name="Map" id="Map">
<area shape="poly" coords="150,40,.." href="?regione=lombardia#tab1" target="_self"/>
...
</map>
```

And then, scrolling in the page:

```
<a id="#tab1">&nbsp;</a>
```

or

```
<span id="#tab1">&nbsp;</span>
```

This solution (old as internet is) is working with all browsers but NOT with Firefox (last versions included) and I spending hours trying to understand what is wrong...
Somebody can help and explain what's happen?
Thanks in advance.